# How to update settings.gradle file in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, plugins, build, apk

Sometimes we get an error while building apk in flutter which is says:

```
Plugin project :ANY_FLUTTER_PACKAGE not found. Please update settings.gradle.
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this in flutter app -> android -> settings.gradle

```
 def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()

 def plugins = new Properties()
 def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')
 if (pluginsFile.exists()) {
    pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) }
}

 plugins.each { name, path ->
    def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
    include ":$name"
    project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
}
```